# AJAX 500 Internal Server ERROR But The Proccess is Success

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I am Facing Problem With Ajax It Keep Showing 500 internal Server Error
But The Ajax Proccess is Success I don't know Why I Have Been Trying To Fix This All Day But I Got Nothing But Weird Is The Process Is Success

Here is My Ajax Code

```
<script type="text/javascript" >  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#add_button').click(function(){  
           $('#user_form')[0].reset();  
           $('.modal-title').text("Add User");  
           $('#action').val("Add");  
           $('#user_uploaded_image').html('');  
      })  
      var dataTable = $('#user_data').DataTable({  
      });  
      $(document).on('click', '.delete_image', function(){  
           var user_id = $(this).attr("id");  
           var link = $(this).attr("style");  
           var mana = $(this).attr("name");  
           //console.log()
           var dom_parent = $(this).context.parentElement.parentElement


           if(confirm("Apakah Anda Yakin Ingin Menghapus Data Gambar Ini?"))  
           {
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>produk/hapus_gambar",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:{mana:mana,link:link,user_id:user_id},  
                     success:function(data)  
                     {  
                          alert(data);
                     }  
                });  
           }  
           else  
           {  
                return false;       
           }  
      });  
 });  



 </script>
```

And This Is My Button Code

```
 <td align="center"> <button type="button" name="gambar" id="<?=$list_produk['id']?>" class="btn btn-danger delete_image" style="<?= $list_produk['gambar']; ?>"><img style="width:120px; height:120px;" src="http://localhost/proyek/gambar/thumb/<?=$list_produk['gambar']?> "></button></td>
```

Here Is My Script That Handle The Process

```
function hapus_gambar() {
    $data['link'] = $_POST['link'];
    $data['id']   = $_POST['user_id'];
    $data['mana'] = $_POST['mana'];  


    $select =$this->db->query('SELECT `gambar` FROM `produk` WHERE `id` = "'.$data['id'].'"');
    foreach($select->result_array() as $gambar) {


    unlink('./gambar/'.$data['link']);
    unlink('./gambar/thumb/'.$data['link']);    




    }
    $query =$this->db->query("DELETE '".$data['mana']."' FROM `produk` WHERE id = '".$data['id']."' ");
    echo 'Data Telah Dihapus';  
    }
```

I Am Using Codegniter

Thank You

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

Turns Out Some Of My Query Makes It Error 
So I change My Query Little Bit And It Works

Thanks For The Help

Comment: What is the point of your select query if you aren't using the data to do anything?